# Import data app ruby on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, pg

I have been trying to import data to my ruby on rails aplication 4.2 hosted in heroku with a database in pg. 
I tried this tutorial and it didnt worked:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast
Say no method import in dreams controller.

Any body knows a good way to import data to my app?
Thanks!
Felipe

Comment: Silly question but, did you remember to push the files to the remote?

Comment: I dont have connection between my db in local (Mysqlite) and the db in remote (Pg). Im migrating the data from another version of the website to the new one in ruby on rails. So im trying to prove with csv, to begin migrating the information. I don't know if this is your question? i'm right? Thanks for your collaboration!

Comment: This is the screenshot of the error: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/bc54becd-2c39-4ec7-b139-f9defc7651f0/9caea62319ac2ecad30ac0738931a649

Comment: Is the local instance the same application as you're running on Heroku? Are you only changing databases or are you also changing applications?

Answer (score 0):

If it says no method `import` in dreams_controller it would appear that you did not properly define the `import` method.  In other words, you either skipped or messed up this portion of the tutorial:

**/app/controllers/products_controller.rb**

```
def import
  Product.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

If you could post the code it would be much easier to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is my dreams_controller.rb: def import
  Dream.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root, notice: "Dreams imported."
end
end

Comment: If you look at the tutorial, it takes the path of the file to be imported as the parameter in params.  IE. `Product.import(params[:file])`  Then the `import` method on the `Dream` model parses that file.  You're passing `id` as the param with a value of `import` which just isn't going to work.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks man! look, i'm trying this:private
    def set_dream
      @dream = Dream.find(params[Rails.root + "app/csv/estructura.csv"])
    end this is the result: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/0b40a56f-e21a-4404-8046-fdd85f887460/1ab9b0e0cb7d7885afa07708d08f4d70

Comment: So here's the deal ... the `find` method ***always*** expects a database ID as a parameter and ***always*** raises an exception if it cant find a model with that ID in the database.  Obviously you don't have a `Dream` object in the database with a big long path name as it's ID.  Change `Dream.find(...)` to `Dream.import(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/csv/estructura.csv'))` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi Mat! Thanks for your answer man! i dont have Dream.find in my dream controller. Any way i did what you said and the result is: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/f0d0c94f-00e7-4beb-9273-263446b67d46/a7832a39089fa167ca192df1398c103c

Answer (score 0):

The missing method is inside `dream.rb` model . You need this:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Dream.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

That is because when you call `Dream.import(params[:file])` you are actually calling the class method of the Dream model.

Comment: This is my dream.rb: def self.iported(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do ⎮row⎮
 Dream.create! row.to_hash
 end
end

Comment: self.iported  should be self.import . Was that a typo in stackoverflow or in your code?

Comment: Could you explain me a little bit more? :) Thanks! i made it as in the tutorial, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is what i get: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/5a99df73-f4a6-405e-8b4e-6785a6c3025f/1d6e1e2a7285560241137e65e39c31ed     In my code

Comment: Looking to the error image you've posted, we can say for sure that your action in the controller is being called. GREAT! However, the error complains that the function IMPORT does not exists for the class DREAM that you are trying to use when you do Dream.import inside the controller. Altough, the definition of Dream.import is inside of dream.rb  so you must have copied and pasted something wrong in this model

Comment: This is what i have in my dreams_controller: def import
  Dream.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root, notice: "Dreams imported."
end
end

Comment: You mean that the problem is solved and mabe i am not importing the right csv, with the right structure of database?

Comment: You need to pass the path to the file to be imported.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure of what I've said in this last comment, so I took it off. Tell me something, your root_path is the Dream show action?

Comment: I found this example in the example code of the tutorial:   def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      product.save!
    end
  end could you explain me where i have to add the path of the file please? i must to replace param with this path?

Comment: I'trying with this path: /Users/felipevelasquez/Desktop/SOS/LAPAPAYA/DB/estructura.csv but its not working: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/69aec505-4145-44db-95fc-08ea540f750c/e7405d14cdc1d2860ac4a1e9b34aa6db sorry! i'm newe, and i have been trying for this for a months, thanks for your collaboration!

Comment: Here i continue working! https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/95a27450-b5a4-45ab-944b-aaa7206d9329/c744e68a7e4e23e832a274ac85bb5071